# Does anyone know or can resolve this kind of Internal Error on Anylogic?

Tags: java, anylogic

I am currently working on a Urban Traffic Simulation on Anylogic and sometimes when the simulation is running, this error appears and everything stop:
"Exception during discrete event execution:
java.lang.RuntimeException: root.[139]:
INTERNAL ERROR: Trying to send car to the logical not where the car is currently located."
The number "139" on the error is not a fix value, it varies depending the time of the simulation progress.
Does anyone know what this error means and how to solve it?
Thank you for all the support, this would be very helpful for the continuation of my work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUgFu.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUgFu.png)

Comment: Did you saw the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Do you have multiple road networks in your model?

Comment: "Do you have multiple road networks in your model?" - No, I only have one Road Network, with 8 roads and 2 intersections.

Comment: "Did you saw the stacktrace of the error?" Yes, even tought, I cannot track the error issue. You can access the printscreen on my problem description above if you are able to help me. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

These errors are very hard to solve. You can only retrace your steps that led up to it and remove your changes one by one until you see what causes the problem.

The number simply tells you which car is facing the issue, but the root problem seems to be some road network issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per mentioned by Benjamin, the [139] refers to the car in the simulation. Basically you can try to observe which car that trigger the error. I fixed the problem by tracing back the car from the source and match the travel direction with the logic as well modify the road and lane switching. I believe there is conflict to the car when it tries to decide which turn to take based on initial route calculation. Please update if this help. The RTL is very generic and to replicate the actual traffic logic would produce complicated model. However, it would be easier to troubleshoot for specific route & logic.

Answer (score 0):

Benjamin and Jauhari already gave you some insights, but still, I'll give you my own answer, hoping it helps you as well. The error speaks for itself: it seems you are saying the car to go to the same place where it is already located. How are you choosing where to go with the car? As I saw in your image, you have a road going S-N, then a connection to go S-W and another road going E-W. Since they are all in the same network, you could say the car to start in the south node and to go to the west node and it will automatically choose the best road to go from one place to the other one. However, if you are choosing the connection between roads A-B-C explicitly in that order, and you're doing it as the car leaves each previous road (i.e. choosing road B once you left road A) it can give you that error, since the car might already be in the road you are telling him to go to.